# Null valued expression

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```
foreach ($OldAccount in $forwarderarray) {

$OldAccount.ForwardingAddress = $OldAccount.ForwardingAddress.substring(0,1).toupper()+$OldAccount.ForwardingAddress.substring(1).tolower() 

$Separatorforwarderaddress = $OldAccount.UserPrincipalName.IndexOf("@") # This section truncates the SMTP address to the firstname.surname to remove the @
$LeftPartforwarderaddress = $OldAccount.UserPrincipalName.Substring(0, $Separatorforwarderaddress) 
$RightPartforwarderaddress = $OldAccount.UserPrincipalName.Substring($Separatorforwarderaddress + 2)  
$SeparatorOwnerAddress = $OldAccount.ForwardingAddress.IndexOf(".") # This section truncates the SMTP address to the firstname.surname to remove the @
$LeftPartOwnerAddress = $OldAccount.ForwardingAddress.Substring(0, $SeparatorOwnerAddress)$RightPartOwnerAddress = 
$OldAccount.ForwardingAddress.Substring($SeparatorOwnerAddress + 2)
```

What is strange is the write host displays the value expected
But when I try to SMTP

```
Send-MailMessage -to $OldAccount.ForwardingAddress
```

I ge:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Can someone please help? What I am trying to achieve is to take out the email address for display purposes and to make the name start with a capital letter.

So why does this display the correct information

```
Write-Host "Sending message, to:"$OldAccount.ForwardingAddress
```

Comment: send-mailmessage is what? a function or external program?

Comment: its an internal function. But I have solved this in the meantime